# Deploying in azure with --net doesn't bind

Tags: azure, docker, deployment

I am trying to deploy a docker container that has to use other external services so I added the `--net` flag while running the container.

```
docker run -it --net=host -p 8090:8000 --env-file=.env -v /etc/logs:/logs --restart=always -d  --name=rank rank
```

But when I check my docker's containers with `docker ps -a` it doesn't show that the port binding is correctly done. Nevertheless, if I remove the `--net` flag it runs but it can't communicate to Redis docker.

[image: Not binding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `--net=host` the port mapping has no effect. You are running the container on your host network, so whichever port the program inside your container is binding to, is bound to the host.

You cannot change the port, the only way would be to have the port inside the container controlled using a environment variable or a config.

`docker` doesn't through an error when both options are used but it ignores the port mapping as such when `--net=host` is used. So that is the reason your container runs but doesn't show any port mapping